# Robust development/production switch for Apache and CLI

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I have seen multiple q&a's around using `getenv()` in the database.php`enter code here` to switch dynamically from a **dev db** to a **prod db**. This really works fine as long as the scirpt is evoked by Apache as the this is an Apache env var.

But I struggle to use that when running a console script (e.g. EmailQueue).

This what I use:

```
        if (getenv('CAKEPHP_DEVELOPMENT')) {
        $this->default = $this->development;
    } else {
        $this->default = $this->production;
    }
```

Is there a way to detect the server I am running on both in Apache and CLI? `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` seems not be te defined in CLI mode.

Thanks,
Lars

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/25/dynamic-database-switching/
which works quite well with CLI and web.

It uses `domain` for web, and `path` for CLI to determine the current environment.